# Python write decorator for static method

Tags: python, regex, caching, decorator, static-methods

I am trying to make a function that will cache some of it's attributes as these take some computation to return a result. Since it is the same result, I wanted to cache this in some way that allows for reusing.

Some code to put this in perspective:

This is what my proposed decorator looks like:

```
def cachedAttributes(func, **kwargs):
    func.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    return func
```

The class method I am trying to decorate:

```
class someclass:
    @staticmethod
    def method(*args):
        # compile regex operation
        # compile regex operation
        # compile regex operation

        # compute and return something
        ...
        pass
```

This is how I am using the decorator

```
class someclass:
    @staticmethod
    @cachedAttributes(method, doctyperegex = re.compile(r'<!DOCTYPE.*?>\s*', re.S|re.U),
                  htmlregex = re.compile(r'<html.*?>\s*', re.S|re.U),
                  metaregex = re.compile(r'<meta(.*?)>', re.S|re.U))
    def method(*args):
        # compile regex operation
        # compile regex operation
        # compile regex operation

        # compute and return something
        ...
        pass
```

So the above is a representation of what I am working with. I have a class which has a static method that uses some regex objects to do some computations, and I want to cache the result of the `compile regex` operations. However this gives me the following error:

```
@staticmethod
NameError: name 'method' is not defined
```

I know this is due to having not defined the method before trying to decorate it, but how else can I do this? Is there a builtin that can do this for me?

Comment: From [_What New in Python 2.4_](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.4.html?highlight=decorator): "Decorator functions can take arguments. If arguments are supplied, your decorator function is called with _only_ those arguments and must return a new decorator function; this function must take a single function and return a function, as previously described."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow this common pattern: you want a function which takes the intended parameters and returns a decorator function.

```
def cachedAttributes(**kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        func.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        return func
    return decorator
```

Then:

```
class someclass:
    @staticmethod
    @cachedAttributes(doctyperegex = re.compile(r'<!DOCTYPE.*?>\s*', re.S|re.U),
              htmlregex = re.compile(r'<html.*?>\s*', re.S|re.U),
              metaregex = re.compile(r'<meta(.*?)>', re.S|re.U))
    def method(*args):
        # compile regex operation
        # compile regex operation
        # compile regex operation

        # compute and return something
        ...
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I knew about the nested function thing, but I didn't know what parameters to pass to it, so I never included it

Answer (score 1):

Your decorator will be passed the `method` function when Python applies the decorator. You do *not* need give your decorator factory the method as an argument:

```
@cachedAttributes(doctyperegex = re.compile(r'<!DOCTYPE.*?>\s*', re.S|re.U),
              htmlregex = re.compile(r'<html.*?>\s*', re.S|re.U),
              metaregex = re.compile(r'<meta(.*?)>', re.S|re.U))
```

Your `cachedAttributes()` callable then returns the actual decorator:

```
def cachedAttributes(**kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        func.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        return func
    return decorator
```

So Python calles `cachedAttributes()`, which returns a decorator. That is then called passing in the function object and the return values is used as the replacement of the decorated function. That can be the original function object, like you are doing here.